# How to spit a string into groups?

Tags: javascript, string, split

Assuming I had a random string:

```
string = "223243902345676";
```

How would I divide this string into groups of four in Javascript, to have:

```
string = ['0223','2439','0234','5676'];
```

Comment: So you prepend zeros to fill in the missing numbers? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried a playing around with the .splice function, but to no avail

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this code

```js
// 0. declare input value
const input = '223243902345676'
const inputs = input.split('')

// 1. get how many zero padding
const padding = 4 - inputs.length % 4

// 2. get zero padding array
const zeroItems = []
for (let i = 0; i < padding; i++) {
  zeroItems.push(0)
}

// 3. concat 2 array (now we get items with zero padding)
const mergeItems = zeroItems.concat(inputs)

// 4. get each item of 4 characters and put to result
const result = []
const LEN = mergeItems.length / 4
for (let i = 0; i < mergeItems.length; i += LEN) {
  const resultItems = mergeItems.slice(i, i + LEN)
  result.push(resultItems.join(''))
}

console.log(result) // print ["0223", "2439", "0234", "5676"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I will do it.

`yourString.match(/.{1,4}/g);`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method with the '0' padding;

```
let string = '223243902345676';
const fourDigits = /\d{4}/g;

const result = string
    .split('')
    .reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
        let padding = '0' + prev;
        return (index === 1) ? padding += curr : prev += curr;
    })
    .match(fourDigits);

console.log(result);

// ['0223','2439','0234','5676'];
```